# Is poll(2) guaranteed to work with duplicated file descriptors?

Tags: c, posix

I use `poll(2)` extensively for multiplexing I/O which allows me to have a single function per thread collecting all filled `pollfd` entries from the workers, polling them and returning the entries back to the workers for processing. All other IO calls are non-blocking.

This works really nicely but as I am expanding the workers, it would simplify my work if some `pollfd` entries could contain the same file descriptor twice or more, perhaps with the same set of expected events or not. But I did not find any guarantees or warnings whether `poll` can handle this.

So, can `poll` handle entries with duplicated file descriptor with possibly the same/different set of events? For example

```
struct pollfd entries[]={{fd,POLLIN,0},{fd,POLLOUT,0},{fd,POLLIN|POLLOUT,0}};
```

- If `fd` is writeable will **all** `entries` with `POLLOUT` in `events` have `POLLOUT` in `revents`?
- If `fd` is readable, ... `POLLIN`...?
- Will any errors on `fd` show on **all** `entries` with that `fd`?
- Will `poll` return the true number of active entries? I.e. those with non-zero `revents`.
- Will `poll` itself not return any errors?
  Example:

```
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
    int fd = 0;
    struct pollfd entries[] = {
        {fd, POLLIN, 0}, {fd, POLLOUT, 0}, {fd, POLLIN | POLLOUT, 0}};

    if( /* FD is writeable */1)
    {
        // No errors for simplicty
        // POLLOUT not queried -> not filled.
        assert(entries[0].revents == 0);
        // POLLOUT queried -> filled.
        assert(entries[1].revents == POLLOUT);
        // POLLOUT queried again -> filled AGAIN. THIS MUST WORK
        assert(entries[2].revents == POLLOUT);
    }
    if( /* FD is readable */1)
    {
        // No errors for simplicty

        // POLLIN queried -> filled.
        assert(entries[0].revents == POLLIN);
        // POLLIN not queried -> not filled.
        assert(entries[1].revents == 0);
        // POLLIN queried again -> filled AGAIN. THIS MUST WORK.
        assert(entries[2].revents == POLLIN);
    }
}
```

The case I have to avoid is that only some entries are filled by `poll`, e.g. only `entries[1]` has `POLLOUT` in `revents` but not `entries[2]`.

What about `epoll`?

Comment: This Q might benefit from a [mcve] showing how you'd want to do this. Like just a `main` with poll on stdin with 2 entries. And no threads needed for this code, I guess.

Comment: @hyde I am not asking about how to do it, I am asking whether polling `entries` will fill them as I expect in my listed questions. So I am not sure exactly what example is required.

Comment: Aren't `fd`s unique for a given process?  I think API is going to `OR` those settings for a given `fd` as `POLLIN`, `POLLPRI` & `POLLOUT` etc are `bit-flags`.

Comment: @SparKot Yes, they are unique, I have only a single process though.

Comment: I would assume for both poll and epoll that *either* all the entries in the poll list behave identically *or* you invoke some kind of undefined behaviour. There's nothing mentioned about requirements in the [documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/poll.html) I find  so I'd rather expect the former...

Comment: Really, just `pipe()` and `fork()`  and test it. My reading of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/poll.html would tell me, that it should set the event for all, as it is true for all.

Comment: Seems like it works `#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <poll.h>

int main (void) {
    FILE* pFile = fopen ("testPoll.txt", "w+");
    if(NULL == pFile) exit (1);

    struct pollfd entries[] = {
        { pFile->_fileno, POLLIN, 0},
        { pFile->_fileno, POLLOUT, 0},
        { pFile->_fileno, POLLIN | POLLOUT, 0}
    };

    if (poll (entries, 3, 0) <= 0) {
        printf ("ERROR: Poll failed");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int pi =0; pi < 3; ++pi)
        printf ("%d : %x\n", pi, entries[pi].revents);

    fclose (pFile);
    return 0;
}
`

Comment: Hm... There might be a difference; according to wikipedia, `poll` is O(n) which might mean that the event handler iterates over the array and sets every FD matching, while `epoll` is O(1). Wondering how that would achieve to set multiple FD then??? So in that case only one single FD might be set. Maybe epoll_ctl fails, if the FD is already set.

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to specify the fd more than once. Also: it is not needed.

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments, yes it seems to work for me too as expected but I would like to have some guarantee that it will continue to work.

Comment: @wildplasser With respect, I did not show my codebase so I have no idea how can you judge whether it is needed or not. I for one think it would be a bad idea to needlessly complicate the current code. This way, the individual workers for example do not have to be aware of each other when working with multi-consumer, multi-producer queues. That is highly desired.

Comment: With no respect: if you have two entries referring to the same fd: what do they **mean**? If one entry leads to a read(), what do you expect the other entry to represent? It would return -1/EWOULDBLOCK, so basically a wasted system call. Also: when removing the fd, you would need to remove two entries. For no reason at all.

Comment: @wildplasser Okay, imagine dynamic array of workers, each having its IN and OUT queue using eventfd - file descriptor. Based on their inner state they either want to read or write. The main thread will obtain the created pollfd entries from all workers. But some entries will contain the same file descriptor . Either because two workers want both to read from the queue(multi consumer) or because one want to write other read. This happens independently and changes between iterations so the polling function does not want to care about duplicates - just collect, poll, distribute.

Comment: @wildplasser No, I do not need to remove the fds twice since the workers do not own them, they are owned by the queues, **which are shared**, hence the possible duplicates. Yes, it will block, either I will waste syscall in `read` or in `pthread_mutex_lock` and additionaly I will have complex logic deduplicating and redistributing the fds, I do not see the benefit. Also you cannot poll both FD and a mutex together.

Comment: From my reading of the source code https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.5/source/fs/select.c#L750 , I think it's totally possible for an event to happen on  a separate CPU right between polling for one fd and another, thus only one will be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is at best unspecified. If you are creating an application, you should *not* depend on the behavior of that when an event is received, all `revents` will have it set.

Note, that when `poll` returns something in `revent`, the actual state *may* potentially change *between* the end of the call to `poll` and your call to anything else. So even if you have `POLLIN`, there may be nothing to be read.

> Is poll(2) guaranteed to work with duplicated file descriptors?

Sure.

> If fd is writeable will all entries with POLLOUT in events have POLLOUT in revents?
>
> If fd is readable, ... POLLIN...?
>
> Will any errors on fd show on all entries with that fd?

It is guaranteed that **at least one** `revents` will be set with the event.

> Will poll return the true number of active entries?

Poll will return how many it has set.

> Will poll itself not return any errors?

No.

> What about epoll?

It's not POSIX. I believe the above also counts for `epoll`, as I did not find any guarantee in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, you even went for the source in your comment, thanks! Okay then, I will have to investigate whether "at least one" is good enough for me. You are right about the `POLLIN` not guaranteeing input so that's almost the same as not having `POLLIN` in `revents` and my code can of course handle the former.